# Calculating thickness of 3D geometry of a model

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, finite-element-analysis, thickness

I am doing finite element modelling. I have a geometry which does not have a uniform thickness and I want to calculate the thickness of that in 4 distinct nodes and compare it with another model. Is there any method to calculate the thickness of the 3D model? (the 3D model can be exported in the format of .stl,.obj,.wrl,.feb.geo and some other formats )

Comment: Please add more details to allow for usable answers. What information you have access to (node locations etc) and what programming environment are you using. If this is not a programming question, but a [Mathematics.SE] question then consider posting this elsewhere.

Comment: How do you define "thickness" ?

Comment: I am using FEBio software and the question is a programming question. Actually, the FEBio software does not calculate the thickness however it provides nodes number, location and etc. However, I can not use the FEBio for measuring the thickness, therefore, it depends on the new software proposed that measures the thickness and whether to provide more information or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to import the mesh into a CAD package and take measurements directly from there.

In the ANSYS world you can export the deflected mesh as an STL file and import it into SpaceClaim. Then the CAD package can auto-patch the mesh to create a solid for further processing, or just use the measurements tools to get what you want.

Comment: Why "the best" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust - given the lack of details in the post, going the CAD way would yield the results the fastest without having to re-invent the wheel. CAD packages do analytic geometry all day long and the user just can tap into that power.

Comment: @YvesDaoust of course it depends if this is a one-off thing, or if it would need to be repeated and automated. Again, stunning lack of definition and requirements in the original post for the scope of such a project.

Comment: Well, assume on the contrary that the OP is after an automated solution, then import in a CAD package could be the worst. [Comments crossed] Without more details, the "best" is absolutely unknown.